# Как проверять пользователя на бота?

Tags: javascript, discord

Я делаю это для команды userinfo, так что `message.member.bot` не работает.
Есть переменная:

```
const mentioneduser = message.mentions.users.first();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mentioneduser.bot) return;
```

Незачто)